# New complete install of MySQL on Win7. Didn't prompt for username?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

The detailed Oracle setup that followed the beginning installation prompted me for a password, and to reenter that, but never asked what a username should be.  So I don't know what mine is.

It's 7 years since set up MySQL on a Windows machine, and the process seems to have gotten more complicated.  If it's any indication of where I am in all of this, just to see what would happen I typed "MySQL" at my command prompt, and it returned with "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I have a JDBC connection (I'm ordinarily going in through PHP), but I haven't filled in the resin-web.xml with anything yet because I don't know what my MySQL username is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you zerkms.  I'll try that, but I have another question befor that's tried.  I'll post it in the same MySQL area in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` is the default user in MySQL.